# Selecting two tables to insert into list using PDO

Tags: php, mysql, sql-server, database, pdo

I have one database named dbtest and two tables in it named tbl_admin and tbl_users. They have the same columns or variables, they are identical, I just seperate it into two so that I'll know where to put users and admins . I'am creating a table lists for all users including the admin but my problem is I can't insert two tables and I'm using PDO type of php. Can you please help me. Thanks

```
  <?php
     require_once 'class.user.php';
    $user = new USER();

    $stmt = $user->runQuery("SELECT * FROM tbl_admin ORDER BY userID DESC");
    $stmt->execute();
    while($row=$stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
    {
    ?>
```

I tried this code;

```
<?php
 require_once 'class.user.php';
$user = new USER();

$stmt = $user->runQuery("SELECT * FROM tbl_admin, tbl_users ORDER BY userID DESC");
$stmt->execute();
while($row=$stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
{
?>
```

and also this one;

```
<?php
 require_once 'class.user.php';
$user = new USER();

$stmt = $user->runQuery("SELECT * FROM tbl_admin ORDER BY userID DESC;
                         SELECT * FROM tbl_users ORDER BY userID DESC;");
$stmt->execute();
while($row=$stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
{
?>
```

but it still doesn't work. How can I select my two tables to insert it into my lists?

Comment: take a look at `UNION` http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/union.html

Comment: why do you need two tables? Anytime two tables are identical except one piece of "meta" data, that metadata can go into a field in one SINGLE table, e.g. `id,username,fullname,is_admin`